# Make a prisma data call dynamic (i.e. this.prisma['dataType'].count())

Tags: typescript, nest, prisma

I am trying to create a count function that I can include in all of my objects.  In my 'core' file, Prisma is this.  So I can do things like `this.user.count()` or `this.company.count()`

I have tried creating a function called count like this

```
count(dataType) {
 return this['dataType'].count()
}
```

So that from every other place in the app, I could just call count('dataType').

My function is actually a good bit more complex - as all this work for a one-line to one-line replacement wouldn't make sense, but this is the idea.  No way I've tried works - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the `Prisma.ModelName` which can return to you all the models u have in your prisma
then u can reference it like this

```
this.prismaService[this.modelName].count()
```

or you can pass "Prisma.ModelName" it as a generic Type to a class then use the above example